# How can I convert Affymetrix microarray data to bedgraph format?

Tags: r, microarray, format-conversion, chip-seq

I've previously asked a different question about the ChIP-chip microarray data that I'm working on. I'm new to this so I'm sorry for asking here again.

I have .CEL files and I'm using the *Affy* package for R to read them. After I load all the files in, I then normalise the data and  generate a .txt file containing the expression values of each file (ranging from 11 to 12). Column 1 contains the gene names and the rest of the  columns contain the expression values for each of the files.

I was wondering if there is a way to convert these data to bedgraph or BED format? What I'd like to do is a metagene analysis but I don't know how that would be possible with expression value data.

I looked online and there are some kinda relevant suggestions/solutions, but they are for Windows machines and I'm working on MacOS.

Comment: Do the generated txt files contain the physical coordinates of the probes? If so, converting them to BED should be a simple matter of rearranging the columns (or they might already be valid BED files).

Comment: Hi Konrad, thank you for your response.

The generated txt file does not contain the coordinates of the probes, however, I have a gff file that contains all this information and I guess I could look up the coordinates for each gene of the array. However, I don't know how the expression values could be converted?

Comment: Why makes the solutions for Windows specific for Windows? Did you try to overcome these using equivalent programs or formats?